# inner queries with outer group by column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table called s2s_actions:

```
    id  brand_id  event_type
------  --------  ----------
    22       361           0
    29       361           1
    35         7           1
    40         7           0
    41        37           1
    42        37           0
    43        37           1
```

and I want to get the count of event_type=0 and count of event_type=1 for each brand_id:

```
SELECT s2s_actions.brand_id, deposits.deposit_amount, signups.signup_amount 
FROM 
s2s_actions,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS signup_amount FROM s2s_actions WHERE brand_id=s2s_actions.brand_id AND event_type=0) signups,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS deposit_amount FROM s2s_actions WHERE brand_id=s2s_actions.brand_id AND event_type=1) deposits
GROUP BY brand_id
```

If I put a number in the inner selects (like 37), this works ok, but I can't use the brand_id of the outer group...

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `conditional aggregation` such as `select brand_id, count(case when event_type = 0 then 1 end) as signups, count(case when event_type = 1 then 1 end) as deposits from ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using `conditional aggregation`, which is a great option for your particular need.

```
select 
 brand_id, 
 sum(case when event_type = 0 then 1 end) as signups, 
 sum(case when event_type = 1 then 1 end) as deposits 
from s2s_actions
group by brand_id
```

| brand_id | signups | deposits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 361 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 37 | 1 | 2 |

And if you have brand id's without those targeted events and want to display zero rather than null in your results, then coalesce those two rows of code...

```
 coalesce(sum(case when event_type = 0 then 1 end), 0) as signups, 
 coalesce(sum(case when event_type = 1 then 1 end), 0) as deposits
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s2s_actions.brand_id, signups.signup_amount, deposits.deposit_amount
     FROM s2s_actions
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT brand_id, COUNT(*) AS signup_amount
     FROM s2s_actions
     WHERE event_type = 0
     GROUP BY brand_id
) signups 
     ON s2s_actions.brand_id = signups.brand_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT brand_id, COUNT(*) AS deposit_amount
     FROM s2s_actions
     WHERE event_type = 1
     GROUP BY brand_id
) deposits 
     ON s2s_actions.brand_id = deposits.brand_id
     GROUP BY s2s_actions.brand_id;
```

The subqueries calculate the counts for `event_type=0` and `event_type=1` separately, grouping them by the `brand_id`.

The main query joins these subqueries using the `brand_id` as the common column.